# Creating nested Structure Groups using Tridion Core Service

Tags: core-service

I'm using the Tridion Core Service to create Structure Groups and copy them to a specific Publication. I have this working but cannot nest the structure groups properly whilst creating them. I had the same issue when creating folders some time ago and found [this article](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/05/how-to-create-folder-structure-with.html) to be quite useful. It strips out the web dav path and creates folders by each part in the array.

However I cannot do this with structure groups as I need to also add a Directory, Metadata etc.

Does anyone know of the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach should be similar to creating nested folders. Instead of using the FolderData class you would use the StructureGroupData class.

The Directory name could be derived from the structure group name, of course you don't have to physically create the directory. Metadata will depends on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jan, you're right! I forgot I can use the web dav path to get the data of the structure group. So I can use client.Read(WEB_DAV_PATH, new ReadOptions()) as StructureGroupData.